# Is there an option, function, or workaround to detect a decimal in a number with trailing zeros after decimal?

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I am working in R and using grepl in an ifelse and for loop across one row in a data.table. I've already programmatically identified a row that contains no NAs or null values in my dataset (rown=2 for the example below).

There are 127 columns that it iterates across with the majority containing integer values and a few columns with mixed types ranging from 1 to 5 (including 1.000000 and 5.000000).

I'm trying to detect the columns that contain a decimal and them to vector x. But when it gets to the columns with the mixed types, grepl returns false for 1.000000, 2.000000, etc because it reads it as an integer, and skips over adding them to x.

I've tried using grepl after converting the numbers, but using as.character or toString still converts to integer without keeping trailing zeros. If i use format or sprintf, it converts every column and defeats the purpose of the loop.

I could wholesale change all columns to integer, but I then lose the ability to identify the columns that did contain the mix types, which is necessary in this project. I'm trying to create code that could be applied to any new dataset.

I'm having trouble generating a example table because of the same issue of mixed types but it would look something like:

```
dt<-data.table("Heading 1"=c(1,2),"Heading 2"=c(4,3),"Heading 3"=c(1,1.000))

|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |     Heading 3    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         4        |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         3        |      1.000       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

and the grepl function (or solution) needs to return TRUE for "Heading 3" = 1.000 and false for integers. I thought a regex to detect decimals would be the answer.

Current code (modified to apply to the above example table):

```r
x<-c()
rown=2
for (i in 1:length(names(dt)) {
    ifelse(grepl("[.]",dt[rown,..i])==TRUE,
        x<-c(x,i),
        invisible(i))
}
```

Expected result would be for vector x to contain "3". With the current code, x would be empty.

If there's another way to approach it, I would appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Comment: Note on Regular Expression syntax: The period "." represents any character, if you want it represent only a period/decimal point, you need to escape it with "\\".  So `grepl("[\\.]", dt[rown,..i])` should now work.

Comment: And while it is an advanced topic, I think this will be informed by [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). Unfortunately, there are cases where intuitively-equal does not mean digitally equal (c.f., `sqrt(2)^2 == 2` is false). This is not unique to R, it is a factor of floating-point representation where there are limited bits to represent mantissas and exponents. So because R almost always stores only a single class in a frame's column, any `integer` (though you have none there) will be coerced to `numeric`.

Comment: @Dave2e, you can use `"[.]"` or `"\\."`, you don't need to escape the dot within a character-group `[]`. (So code-golf, and perhaps just visual preference :-)

Comment: DavidLee, to clarify one point I made: you do use integer-looking numbers like `1` and `4`, but to R they are numeric, see `class(1)`. If you do `1L` (trailing upper-case "L"), it'll be integer (`class(1L)`), though when within a column that contains a non-integer number, it will be coerced to `numeric`.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the explanation. It makes sense the way it's presented is makes it seem like they are different types and yes they are all of a numeric class.

Comment: @joran I believe identifying things with non-zero fractional parts may be the direction I need to go in order to differentiate these columns. Would you have any advice on how I could start with that? The origin of this data is a haven::read_sas of survey responses and constructed variables. The columns that contain the non-zero fractional parts are of interested because they are all the columns that do not have a sas format label/attribute associated with the variable. I can manually identify these, but I'm trying to make something to address data that can contain thousands of columns.